# How should a model object be passed to a helper function in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the correct way to pass a model object to a helper function in Django?

E.g., I have a user object:

```
u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
```

and then want to perform some operations on `u` using the function `helpers.foo()` before saving back to DB.

Should I pass the entire object and manipulate directly? Or just the ID then re-query the DB within the helper function to get the object again...

Comment: DB queries are neither free nor cheap; although fast.

Comment: If this is done synchronously, pass the instance. For async calls like to a celery task, pass the id (only the id will be serializable anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do a little test:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u1 = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> u2 = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> u1 == u2
True
>>> u1 is u2
False
>>> u1.first_name
u'Ruth'
>>> u2.first_name
u'Ruth'
>>> u2.first_name = u"Route"
>>> u2 == u1
True
>>> u1.first_name
u'Ruth'
>>> u2.save()
>>> u1.first_name
u'Ruth'
>>> 
>>> u1.refresh_from_db()
>>> u1.first_name
u'Route'
```

As you can see, loading the same record twice gives two distinct objects (they compare equal because `Model` compares on pk), and changing one - whether you save the changes or not - does not impact the second one (until you refresh it from the db of course). Also, if you modify and save both, the result might not be what you expected:

```
>>> u1.last_name
u'FOOBAR'
>>> u2.last_name
u'FOOBAR'
>>>
>>> u1.first_name = u"Ruth"
>>> u2.last_name = u"ROOTZ"
>>> u1.save()
>>> u2.save()
>>> ux = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> ux.first_name
u'Route'
>>> ux.last_name
u'ROOTZ'
```

If you factor in db access cost, it seems obvious that you don't want to have your helper function load a second (distinct) instance from the db.

The case of async calls (typically celery tasks) is different - here you want to pass the object's id and have your task load it afresh from the db. The main reason is that the database record migh have been modified between the task call and it's execution (and you don't want to overwrite those modifications).

Comment: Awesome, great answer. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @Rob you're welcome - and feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to pass the complete object, if you pass the id only then you have to again hit the db to get the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking generally, I've added a piece from a working project to the bottom. However, in your case, I believe you can define an instance method to deal with selected objects - of course if those operation is directly related to model.

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ...

    def make_comrade(self):
        return "Comrade " + self.last_name
```

then,

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
user.update(title=user.make_comrade())
```

*The code I've told above.*

in my **views.py**

```
from reports_helper import report_generator

...

def export_terminals_daily_turnover(request):
    return report_generator('TerminalTurnover', 'daily_turnover', 'terminal_id', 'address_on_bill', 'summ')
```

and this is my **reports_helper.py**

```
import csv
import django
from django.http import  HttpResponse


def get_model_name(model_name):
    entity = django.apps.apps.get_model('reports', model_name)
    return entity


def report_generator(model_name, report_name, *args):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}.csv"'.format(report_name)

    headers = list(args)
    klass = get_model_name(model_name)

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(headers)

    rows = klass.objects.all().values_list(*args)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)

    return response
```

btw, the model here I am referring to, is a db view rather than a table

```
class TerminalTurnover(models.Model):
    terminal_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    summ = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    address_on_bill = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'reports_terminalturnover'
```